# Can I connect string with Json attribute like this

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON data like this.

```
data = {
    "purchaseId": 1,
    "name": "Rubbick",
    "date": "2560-06-29",
    "price": 12345.00,
  },
  {
    "purchaseId": 2,
    "name": "Johny",
    "date": "2560-07-14",
    "work": "Navy",
    "price": 15000.00
  }
```

if I need to get element attribute names from JSON I will use  `Object.keys(data[0])` and

I will get `(4) ["purchaseId", "name", "date", "price"]`

so when I used `Object.keys(data[0])[1]` my result is `name`

then I will keep `var nameOfAtt = Object.keys(data[0])[1]`

And I need to use in

```
var results = [];
var keyword = "Johny";
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j < Object.keys(data[i]).length; j++){
        if( data[i].Object.keys(data[i])[j] == keyword){
           results.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

so I will get data object that only have Johny

My question I can't use `data[i].Object.keys(data[i])[j]` It showed unidentified but I can use `data[i].name`

How can I connect string like this.

Comment: You should look at `Array.filter()`

Comment: There's something wrong with the `data` (missing brackets?), please fix it.

Comment: Teemu is right. `data` won't parse because it's not an array, at least not in the example you've provided.

Comment: Please also note that the order of keys in an object is not guaranteed.

Comment: [This has nothing to do with JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix your data, here's a quick ES6 example to show you how to filter out the objects you want from the data.

```
const getObjFromKey = (data, key, value) => {
  return data.filter((obj) => obj[key] === value);
}

const result = getObjFromKey(data, 'name', 'Johny');
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "purchaseId": 2,
    "name": "Johny",
    "date": "2560-07-14",
    "work": "Navy",
    "price": 15000
  }
]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/u5ggxbzw/)

Answer (score 0):

data should be an array and you can use filter property like this :

```
var attrData = ["purchaseId", "name", "date", "price"],
data = [
  {
    "purchaseId": 1,
    "name": "Rubbick",
    "date": "2560-06-29",
    "price": 12345.00,
  },
  {
    "purchaseId": 2,
    "name": "Johny",
    "date": "2560-07-14",
    "work": "Navy",
    "price": 15000.00
  }
];
var keyword = 'Johny';

var filtered = data.filter(function(dataItem){
    return dataItem[attrData[1]] === keyword;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for search function like this

```
var data = [{
            "purchaseId": 1,
            "name": "Rubbick",
            "date": "2560-06-29",
            "price": 12345.00,
        },
                {
                    "purchaseId": 2,
            "name": "Johny",
            "date": "2560-07-14",
            "work": "Navy",
            "price": 15000.00
        }];

        function search(name){
            var result = [];
            data.forEach(function(obj){
                if(obj.name == name)
                    result.push(obj);
            });
            return result;
        }

        //lets search 
        var rs = search("Johny");
        console.log(rs);//output results to console log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{
        "purchaseId": 1,
        "name": "Rubbick",
        "date": "2560-06-29",
        "price": 12345.00,
      },
      {
        "purchaseId": 2,
        "name": "Johny",
        "date": "2560-07-14",
        "work": "Navy",
        "price": 15000.00
      }];

      var results = [];
      var keyword = "Johny";
      for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
          for(var j=0; j < Object.keys(data[i]).length; j++){
              if( data[i][Object.keys(data[i])[j]] == keyword){
                 results.push(data[i]);
              }
          }
      }
```